# Making a GCF calculator in python

Tags: python, math, calculator

I'm making a calculator in python that takes in two numbers and returns the greatest common factor of it. When I create a function that returns the same numbers of the two lists of factors, I keep getting a 'index' error even if I stated

```
if len(one) == 0 and len(two) == 0:
```

here's my code:

```
def work(one, two):
        for i in range(len(one)):
            for j in range(len(two)):
                if len(one) != 0 and len(two) != 0:
                    if one[i] == two[j]:
                        one.pop(i)
                        two.pop(j)
                        if len(one) == 0 or len(two) == 0:
                            break
                        else:
                            work(primeF, primeF2)
            break
work(primeF, primeF2)
```

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: What is this even trying to do?  You never return anything.  Are the arguments to `work` lists or numbers?  What are `primeF` and `primeF2`?  The gcf involves divisibility, but you only ever check equality.

Comment: This is only part of the code, and I'm trying to work on lists, not numbers.

Comment: Then you need to post a [mcve].  "What are `primeF` and `primeF2`?  Are they list of factors?  Lists of prime factors?  Or are you content with the answer you've accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code by using what is already available in Python's standard library:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> work = fractions.gcd
>>> work(12345, 67890)
15
```

The `fractions.gcd` function should do exactly what you want without the need for more code. Here is a copy of the function from the module's source:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b.

    Unless b==0, the result will have the same sign as b (so that when
    b is divided by it, the result comes out positive).
    """
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

**Addendum:**

As noted in the comments by [kmui2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8109319/kmui2), the `gcd` function should be imported from the `math` module instead of the `fractions` module since Python's 3.9 release.

Comment: I use an online editor called codeskulptor and I do not have that module inplemented

Comment: `fractions.gcd` has been removed in Python 3.9 https://bugs.python.org/issue39350 in favor of `math.gcd`

Answer (score 1):

I think that instead of checking whether the list length is 0, you need to be checking that the list is long enough to include your index.

Answer (score 0):

There is an even easier way to do it without modules (I just used time for supplements)

```
import time

def gcf (num1, num2): #The Actual Calculator
    if num1 > num2:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1

    for x in range (num1, 0, -1):
        if num1 % x == 0 and num2 % x == 0:
            return x


def run(): #This section is defined so that it can be run multiple times       
    num1 = int(input("First Number: "))  #First number
    num2 = int(input("Second Number: ")) #Second number

    print (str (gcf (num1, num2)))

    run_again = input("Run again? y or yes for yes: ")

    if run_again == "yes" or run_again == "Y" or run_again == "Yes" or 
    run_again == "y": 
        run()
    elif run_again == "hello":
        print("hi")
        run()
    else:
        print("Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        quit()

#Runs the code
run()
```